# Pandas: Setting decimal places for zeros

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe showing regression output. I want to style it for publication. I rounded all values (before putting them between parenthesis) using `df.round(4)`. But zeros stay without any decimal places.

```
                parameter  pvalue   significance 4a
4   x1          0.1119     0.0257   **
4   x1_SE      (0.0502)     
3   x2          0.5996     0        ***
3   x2_SE      (0.1571)
```

simply for optical reasons I'd like to have the same number of decimal places for zeros as well. The result should look like that:

```
                parameter  pvalue   significance 4a
4   x1          0.1119     0.0257   **
4   x1_SE      (0.0502)     
3   x2          0.5996     0.0000   ***
3   x2_SE      (0.1571)
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest to stick to the `.` as a decimal separator!

Comment: my fault, that was a typo. Thank you for making me aware of this

Comment: Sorry to have pointed it out, but I come from Italy and I live in the Netherlands, and both countries use `,` as a decimal separator. And that results in A LOT of headaches! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

You can set up your global pandas properties to display trailing zeros.

```py
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format
```

**Original**

I find it tricky with trailing zeros. A workaround would be to create a column that has corresponding `str` values with trailing zeros.

```py
df['pvalueFormatted'] = df['pvalue'].apply(lambda x: '{:,.4f}'.format(x))
```

Or if you want to save it as a .csv, you could use float_format:

```py
df.to_csv('output.csv', float_format="%,.4f")
```

Comment: thanks @ilyankou. Your update was exactly the solution I was hoping for! I previously tried `pd.set_printoptions(precision=3)` which did not work for me. Do you know how to reactivate the default setting afterwards?

Comment: If you use Jupyter, if you restart your kernel, it should be reset to default. Or try https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.reset_option.html